# Не запускается перемещение нода

Tags: swift, spritekit

Не запускается перемещение нода

```
    let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath()

    rectanglePath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(280, 120))
    rectanglePath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(40, 400))
    rectanglePath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(120, 480))
    rectanglePath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(200, 40))
    rectanglePath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(280, 120))

    followRectangle = SKAction.followPath(rectanglePath.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, duration: 5.0)
    rectangle.runAction(SKAction.sequence([followRectangle]))
```

Ошибка:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Видимо, объект rectangle не создается. Других идей нет - в коде не видно явных ошибок. Попробуйте пошаговую отладку, посмотрите что там в rectangle лежит.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Решил проблему. Действительно, метод передвижения объекта вписал до его вхождения в сцену.